# Watchkit , dismissController function

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller, watchkit, apple-watch

i want to push in another view controller with code

```
 [self pushControllerWithName:@"secondeviewcontroller" context:@"Hello"];
```

its work great for pushing  but for  **dissmiss**

in secondviewcontroller doesn't work

```
 [self dismissController];
```

Comment: Does anything happen when pressed? How are you calling it? Have you verified the method itself is called?

Comment: i called in didSelectRowAtIndex

but this code docent work

Comment: And you've checked that didSelectRowAtIndex is called as you would expect, when you press the table view cell?

Comment: Yes all the function its work just  [self dismissController] isn't work

Comment: Does anything happen when `dismissController` is called? "Isn't work" or "does't work" doesn't give any useful information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a hierarchical interface, you need to to use `[self popController]` to go back after pushing a controller.

`[self dismissController]` is used in modal interfaces.